# Does anyone know a good DVD manipulation component that i can download or buy?

Tags: c#, video, directx, directshow, dvd

We are trying to develope a small C# application to load a DVD (VOB), display it and capture some frames.

This application is going to be comercial so I am looking for a component (DLL maybe) that we can buy and use to A. play the DVD, B. Jump to specific times in the DVD and C. Capture frames.

This is really urgent, so any help would be greatly appriciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/VLC_media_player#cite_note-12 might help.  As also libvlc which has a "snapshot" aspect, perhaps.

Answer (score 0):

This is a little more complicated than you think. Problem is that "timeframe" may be hard to get (navigate through menues, find the RIGHT parts / chapters that are the real movie etc.

Windows 7 has the DirectShow components - you CAN work with DirectShow out of C#, but I would recommend using Managed C++ for that part (the AP is very COM centric, it is simply easier to manipulate them out of a C++ app than a C# part - managed C++ allows you to make a nice managed .NET class that handles all the DirectShow interop).

Windows 7 has standard DVD Decovers on board. Not sure how well they are acessible from DirectShow or whether they are protected form third party applications.

Comment: Thanks TomTom,

I have been playing around with DirectShow for a while, but can't get it to do exactly what i want.

Also i need my application to work on XP machines, but they do not include any DVD decoders by default.

I was hopping somone already created a DLL or somthing that i can interface.

Do you know anything or anyone that can help with this ?

Comment: Yes. Pretty much every commercial encoder comes with irectShow components (this is why it works on Media Player). But they COST - development AND LICENSING must be paid by the user.